# File path issue with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, path

After I created a new workspace on Visual studio code. I type `dotnet run` in the powershell terminal. I get

> couldn't find a project to run, ensure the project exist in "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample workspace" or pass the path to the project using --project.

we used `dotnet run --project`, `dotnet restore`, and `dotnet new console` all this does is create hello world.

> "couldn't find a project to run, ensure the project exist in C:\Users\Desktop\Sample workspace"

Answer (score 1):

> after I created a new workspace on Visual studio code. I type dotnet run

That is expected.  VS Code does not create a new project for you automatically.  You must run `dotnet new <project type>` to create a project.  After creating a project then `dotnet run` should perform as expected.